# What do these buttons mean in a Pulowski Preservation shelter?

Tags: fallout-4

On the inside, Pulowski Preservation shelters are equiped like this:

[image: Pulowski]

These 6 buttons don't have any actual ingame use but they could have meant something in the game history, or maybe an abandoned feature from the game devs.

Is there any clues about what they mean?

Comment: From what I could find, the shelter had some features to it.  For instance, I read that it has oxygen masks in it, which might be what the top left button would control, (it sort of looks like the Oxygen symbol).  The button below it may be perhaps for pumping out water, as it sort of looks like a plunger.  The bottom right one may be for a shower, in case one was contaminated with radioactive filth, or to control the fan on ceiling of the shelter.  The ones above may be door controls, and I've no idea about the bomb looking one.  Perhaps a self destruct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't really know from in-game materials, so we are forced to speculate. Let's look at each button, left-to-right, top-to-bottom:

1. **Oxygen?**

   That looks a lot like the O2 symbol for oxygen. [Nukapedia's Pulowski Preservation Shelter page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pulowski_Preservation_shelter) notes that

> The shelters contain face masks and a fan, suggesting they had some form of ventilation.

I expect that pressing that button would activate the face mask and fan.

2. **Close Door**

If you're inside the shelter, then the door moves to the left when closing, and to the right when opening. This can be seen in this screenshot with the sliding door partially visible, taken from Nukapedia:

[image: open shelter]

So it seems pretty clear that that would control the door.

3. **Suction**

The shelters are equipped with a suction hose, probably for disposing of waste. In other words, it's the toilet. As noted on the Nukapedia page, Bryan Wilks mentions the hose during the Fallout 3 quest Those!

> While standing in the shelter, Bryan Wilks might ask "What's this funny suction hose for?" The answer is unknown, but logical speculation suggests it's used to dispose of biological waste.

4. **Open Door**

As in 2, but reversed.

5. **Unknown**

I think that looks like an inverted bell. Normally, a bell like this would correspond to some kind of alarm, [such as in an elevator](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1darrh/what_is_the_proper_use_of_the_bell_button_on_an/). It could have a similar function the the elevator bell, to indicate to the outside world that the occupant is trapped. Maybe it's supposed to call Pulowski.

It could also have something to do with a Geiger counter, and detecting if it is safe to go outside. After entering, the booth states

> Wait for radiation to clear. Enjoy your stay.

There would need to be some way to determine if the radiation had cleared, so I would hope one of those controls corresponds to a Geiger counter, and this seems like the most likely one.

I could also see that image being interpreted as a falling bomb, with fins on the upper end. This might be more consistent with the Geiger counter interpretation.

6. **Shower?**

That looks an awful lot like a showerhead.

Considering the radiation theme of Fallout, and the specific purpose of the shelter, it seems reasonable to conclude that this is a decontamination shower, possibly for use immediately after entering the shelter.

**Conclusion**

There are some other possible functions. Maybe one of those controls a light. Maybe six is actually the suction, rather than a showerhead. I think we can be pretty confident in the open and close door buttons, at the least.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with all this.  Looks like you and I share the same thoughts based on my comment. I thought of what you said for 5 as well, but I think self-destruct is more appropriate in the Fallout world :)

Comment: I forgot about Fallout 3 version... it would be nice to see if they have the same buttons inside.

Comment: @Bebs Yeah, that would be good to know. It would take about 2 minutes to figure that out if I would remember to check it out.